Magento 2 - After upgrde getting net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES in admin category page
We upgraded Magento from version 2.4.5 to 2.4.7-p3. After that, we checked the admin category page and encountered the following errors:
   POST https://yourdomain.com/admin/catalog/category/categoriesJson/key/d035d0193f07dca2ea53514fb6d5ed3d76c74e7f76e34fd505c126642870a9a1/ net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   POST https://yourdomain.com/admin/catalog/category/categoriesJson/key/d035d0193f07dca2ea53514fb6d5ed3d76c74e7f76e34fd505c126642870a9a1/ net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   POST https://yourdomain.com/admin/catalog/category/categoriesJson/key/d035d0193f07dca2ea53514fb6d5ed3d76c74e7f76e34fd505c126642870a9a1/ net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/arrays.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/compare.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/misc.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/objects.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/strings.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES
    
   GET https://yourdomain.com/static/version1731009637/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/utils/template.js net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES


Help to fix this issue.
Thanks

Please check your logs. You can also check your network tab to see if there is a PHP error in the response to the Ajax request.
